# How to reference JDK11 built custom project classes in a JDK17 project

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, java-11, java-17

I am working on a POC to build a Kafka consumer.

Our primary project that is built is based on **JDK17**, and it has grown bigger hence we cannot downgrade it to **JDK11** now. I know the fact that Kafka is compatible only with **JDK11** and **JDK8** and not with **JDK17**.

**Proposed Solution**

Build the KafkaConnection piece alone using JDK11 and reference in the JDK17 bigger project.

Let's say I have a class in the JDK11 project named `KafkaConsumerConfiguration`. When I import that class using `@Import({KafkaConsumerConfiguration.class})` in the bigger project - I still get the error. How do I avoid the classes built using JDK11 again not be compiled/run with JDK17?

Comment: Edited question as there's no such thing as "Confluent Kafka"

Answer (score 0):

The Apache or Confluent documentation infrastructure components' Java support aren't related to client JVM versions, which do presently work on up to Java 17.

If you're getting an error with Spring annotations, then you'll need to check Spring's own documentation.